How do EMI noise currents actually appear on a wire?
I'm trying to better understand the impact of EMI noise on circuits. Imagine I have the circuit below which is comprised of two series resistors with both ends grounded.
Imagine some EMI noise coming through an inducing a current I_n on the wire. Since the resistors are different on each side, the produced voltages over each resistor will not be balanced. Thus it seems like there will be a short circuit in response to this scenario.
Am I modeling my EMI noise incorrectly? Does it not simply appear as a current on the wire? Or is this some weird phenomenon affect that is difficult to describe?


Induced means that a voltage appears across the wire, so both ends are not at the same potential. When we draw a line in a schematic we typically assume that the potential is identical everywhere along that line (and to every line and node that is connected). That's not exactly true in reality, but it's often a very good approximation, especially at low frequencies, low currents and if we don't look too closely at microvolts.
A wire that has some induced EMF is more like a winding on a transformer.
There are other ways for EMI to affect a circuit. There exists stray capacitance from that connection to everything else in the universe. Sometimes not enough to matter, but sometimes there's a changing electric field that's strong enough to matter, depending on how high impedance that node is.
So you might draw it more like this:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
(the pF shown are just chosen out of the air to illustrate they could be different).
Complicating the matter is that we also typically assume that GND is GND, and of course it's just another connection and voltages can be induced between two connections that we happen to label GND just as easily as the other two.

For an interfering current (\$I_n\$) to be produced, the wire must have inductance (my red addition) and a closed circuit for that current to flow: -

It is the inductance (and the resulting voltage across its terminals) that is what you may be looking for to solve your conundrum.
